# Convert array of objects to one Object using ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an array:

```
var a = [
    {id: 1, val: 'a'},
    {id: 2, val: 'b'},
    {id: 3, val: 'c'},
    {id: 4, val: 'd'},
]
```

And I want to get transform it to:

```
var b = {
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c',
    4: 'd',
}
```

Actually I'm using pure js:

```
var b = a.reduce(
    (ac, pr) => ({
      ...ac,
      [pr.id]: pr.val,
    }),
    {}
  );
```

But maybe Ramda.js have something special for that purpose?

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/

Comment: Note that `id` is coerced to `String` during the transformation. Type coercion can lead to subtle bugs. Instead of using `Object`'s as dictionaries, you should use a proper dictionary: `Map`, where keys can actually be `Number`s.

Comment: If you choose to go with a `Map` rather than a plain object, you can instantiate it using `var b = new Map(a.map(({id, val}) => [id, val]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain Javascript, you could use a combination with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var a = [{ id: 1, val: 'a' }, { id: 2, val: 'b' }, { id: 3, val: 'c' }, { id: 4, val: 'd' }],
    result = Object.assign(...a.map(({ id, val }) => ({ [id]: val })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for Ramda's **[`.mergeAll()` method](http://ramdajs.com/0.20.1/docs/#mergeAll)**:

```
var b = R.mergeAll(a.map(function(o) {
  return {
    [o.id]: o.val
  }
}));
```

The `.map()`call will return the custom object from each item, taking only the values, then `.mergeAll()` will merge the `array` into one `object`.

**`mergeAll` Documentation**:

> Merges a list of objects together into one object.

**Demo:**

```js
var a = [{
    id: 1,
    val: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    val: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    val: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    val: 'd'
  },
];


var b = R.mergeAll(a.map(function(o) {
  return {
    [o.id]: o.val
  }
}));
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/0.18.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where does ramda knows, which property is the key and which the value?

Comment: @NinaScholz [source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/mergeAll.js)

Comment: it looks like the equivalent of `Object.assign`, but the rest is missing for the problem.

Comment: @Nick Yes I updated the answer, it just needs mapping the itesm before calling `.mergeAll()`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well pointed out, thanks. I missed the fact that there are two properties.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone still passes by here, it does indeed:

```
R.indexBy(R.prop('id'), someArray);
```

[See indexBy in Ramda's documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexBy)

EDIT:
Bennet is correct. If we want `val` as the only value per key, we can "pluck" it out after:

```
const createValDict = R.pipe(
  R.indexBy(R.prop('id')),
  R.pluck('val')
)

const valDict = createValDict(myArr)
```

[Pluck works on objects too](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck)

Comment: This is good but doesn't give exactly the result the OP wanted...

Answer (score 3):

Get the ordered values from each object by mapping with [R.props](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#props), and use [R.fromPairs](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#fromPairs) to create an object:

```js
var a = [
    {id: 1, val: 'a'},
    {id: 2, val: 'b'},
    {id: 3, val: 'c'},
    {id: 4, val: 'd'},
];

var result = R.compose(R.fromPairs, R.map(R.props(['id', 'val'])));

console.log(result(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [
    {id: 1, val: 'a'},
    {id: 2, val: 'b'},
    {id: 3, val: 'c'},
    {id: 4, val: 'd'},
]

var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  result[a[i].id] = a[i].val;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted something point-free, you could write:

```
const combine = compose(mergeAll, map(lift(objOf)(prop('id'), prop('val'))))
```

```js
const {compose, mergeAll, map, lift, objOf, prop} = R;

const combine = compose(mergeAll, map(lift(objOf)(prop('id'), prop('val'))))

var a = [{id:1, val:'a'}, {id:2, val:'b'}, {id:3, val:'c'}, {id:4, val:'d'}]
console.log(combine(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/0.18.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it works like a charm :

```js
var a = [
    {id: 1, val: 'a'},
    {id: 2, val: 'b'},
    {id: 3, val: 'c'},
    {id: 4, val: 'd'},
];
// var b = R.fromPairs( a.map(Object.values) );
// Perhaps this is the more general and order independent way:
var b = R.fromPairs(a.map( ({id,val})=>[id,val] ));
console.log( b );
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that this solution relies on the order in which the objects' properties are defined. It will break if, for example, you add `{ val: 'e', id: 5 }`.

Comment: @user3297291 Yes you're right it's case specific , so I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the simplest way:

```
pipe(map(props(['id', 'val'])), fromPairs)(a)
```

[@spflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371552/61754) is simpler but not guaranteed to work on all platforms. Ramda code golf is always fun!

```js
const { fromPairs, map, pipe, props } = R

const a = [
    {id: 1, val: 'a'},
    {id: 2, val: 'b'},
    {id: 3, val: 'c'},
    {id: 4, val: 'd'},
]

const result = pipe(map(props(['id', 'val'])), fromPairs)(a)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet one approach:

```js
const { indexBy, prop, pipe, pluck } = R
const a = [
    {id: 1, val: 'a'},
    {id: 2, val: 'b'},
    {id: 3, val: 'c'},
    {id: 4, val: 'd'},
]
const result = pipe(indexBy(prop('id')), pluck('val'))(a)
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```